# Give an example of two closed disjoint sets $F$ and $G$ (subsets of $\mathbb{R}$) such that $\inf\{|x-y|; x\in F, y\in G\}=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Give an example of two closed disjoint sets $F, G\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $\inf\{|x-y|; x\in F, y\in G\}=0$.

I tried so much! I found that both have to be unbounded, because if one of them is compact, we can find two elements $x_0\in F$ and $y_0\in G$ such that $\inf\{|x-y|; x\in F, y\in G\}=|x_0-y_0|$.

Comment: $\{1,2,\ldots\}$ and $\{1+1/2,2+1/3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Yeah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let one of the sets be the integers. Construct the other set by taking non-integer numbers that "get close to the integers".